# How to communicate to other threads using shared resource?

Tags: java, multithreading, oop

There is auction server which accepts clients and make for each socket connection a new thread to serve client. Each thread has it's protocol. Server have only one instance of Auction object. `Auction` object holds list of `Lot` objects. `Auction` object is passed as argument to client thread. `Protocol` has to have a way to put a bid and notify all client threads somehow. The `makeBid` method exists in `Lot` and it puts bid to list of bids. The next step is to notify all client thread form `makeBid` method. What is the best practice to do this? 
[image]

I tried to use a field (MSG) in Thread to hold a message. Thread checks if `!MSG.isEmpty()` while in `run()`. If `!MSG.isEmpty()` then `ClientThread` prints to socket this `MSG`. I think there is a better solution.

---

```
public class ClientServiceThread extends Thread  {
public String PRINT_NEW_MSG = "";
while (m_bRunThread) {

                if(!PRINT_NEW_MSG.isEmpty()){
                    out.println("PRINT_NEW_MSG: "+PRINT_NEW_MSG);
                    PRINT_NEW_MSG = "";
                String clientCommand = in.readLine();
                                 ...
            }
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't just have the threads wait on a `BlockingQueue`, perhaps, of bid messages?

Comment: it is a good idea with your field. I prefer an observer where all clients will be informed. All clients need to register on the observer. it is a good idea to have only one instance - like your server object. (extend your server with an observer). [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a subscription design that calls a `lotUpdated()` method whenever a client places a bid on a Lot.  Each `ClientThread` would subscribe to the `Lots` that it wants to be notified of.

```
public class Lot {
  private List<ClientThread> clients = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
  private List<Integer> bids = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  public synchronized void subscribe(ClientThread t){
    clients.add(t);
  }

  public synchronized void unsubscribe(ClientThread t){
    clients.remove(t);
  }

  public synchronized void makeBid(int i){
    bids.add(i);
    for (ClientThread client : clients){
      client.lotUpdated(this);
    }
  }
}

public ClientThread {
  public void lotUpdated(Lot lot){
    //called when someone places a bid on a Lot that this client subscribed to
    out.println("Lot updated");
  }
}
```

Comment: Will I have the problem where ClientThread waits for socket input form user *String clientCommand = in.readLine();* and cannot perform "lotUpdated" until user sends message?

Comment: No that shouldn't be a problem.  What would happen is `lotUpdated()` would be called in a different thread from the one that's blocking on `in.readLine()`.

Answer (score 1):

Better you can synchronize the "makeBid" method using this object. Then call notifyAll method

at the end of makeBid.